# Center Container

Tags: html, css

I'm working on making front end design for someone but I don't have access to the css file or classes, so I can't see what's causing the container align left.

I'm looking to center the container on screen. What would be best approach? I tried wrapping div with `text-align: center !important;` that didn't work.

```html
<div class="portlet-content">
  <div class="portlet-content-container">
    <div class="portlet-body">
      <div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="biography-view">
            <div class="biography-item col-md-6">
              <div style="border-style:none">
                <div class="biographyimage" style="background-image:url(http://www.math.uni-frankfurt.de/~person/_4170854.jpg);">&nbsp;</div>

                <div class="caption biography-profile">
                  <div class="biography-profile-content">
                    <h3 class="full-name">Name</h3>

                    <p class="person-title">Company Name</p>

                    <p class="person-title"><strong>Person Title</strong></p>

                    <div class="person-biography">Biography</div>

                    <div class="person-biography collapse" id="readmore">More Person Info</div>
                    <a class="read_more" data-target="#readmore" data-toggle="collapse">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't make sense. if you can see the effects of the CSS in your browser, then you must have the CSS. can you clarify?

Comment: if you are using chrome or firefox, you can right-click on the element in question and choose "inspect element". this should show all the CSS rules being applied to the object and it will show you where the rules are coming from.

Comment: This is true. If you can see the CSS happening in your browser. You can see the CSS on the page. I think what you mean is you don't have access to the files, which is fine. Just inspect the CSS thats happening on that div element and add your own custom CSS to fix the issue.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow  Yes I see that in inspect tool they are using float: left; in class class="biography-item. If i use margin: auto; it will fix my problem. Is there a way to override float and change it to margin: auto?

Comment: @Jorden1337 do you know approact where i can disable float left and set margin to auto?

Comment: @MoiezMalik use the same CSS selector and include it **after** the original. How did you add your `text-align` attempt?

Comment: @MoiezMalik sure. `float: inherit; margin: auto;`.

Comment: @hungerstar I wrap code with <div style="text-align: center !important;"> </div>. also can you give me example as to what you said "use the same CSS selector and include it after the original"

Comment: @hungerstar Got it, for some reason removing !important from style worked. Thank You.

Comment: I would have done it like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/66e2f822f02e6d31f186ac124278eb2e). The issue with the solution you have now is that you're using an inherited property to dictate what happens to child elements. A lot of properties are **not** inherited. Can you insert HTML anywhere in the page?

Answer (score 0):

In a CSS block for the container, you can center it as follows:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use inline styles `<div class="portlet-content" style="text-align:center;">` or somthing yours based on css specificity [mozila MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)